# Error in execution of my OpenGL C program to implement Bresenham's Line Drawing algorithm. Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, gcc, opengl, cygwin, x11

I tried implementing Bresenham's Line Drawing algorithm using C and OpenGL but I am getting an empty window which automatically closes and `Aborted (core dumped)` is printed on my Cygwin Terminal.I then noticed that a ***a.exe.stackdump*** file is generated and then I did a `cat a.exe.stackdump` and it showed some hex values maybe as seen in image below. I compiled the program using `gcc 1lab.c -lglut -lglu -lgl` and `./a.exe`. Can anyone explain what is essentially wrong with my code? The output and program is attached below.

Note: Please kindly ignore any comments as they are irrelevant and are used only because I am modifying existing code by commenting what I don't need.

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void init (void)
 {
    glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 150.0);
 }

GLint **plotterresizer(GLint** plotter)
 {
    return realloc(plotter,2*sizeof(plotter));
 }

int **logic (void)
 {
   GLint **plotter=(GLint**)malloc(2*sizeof(GLint*)) ;
   GLint sp[]={9,18};
   GLint ep[]={14,22};
   GLint xy[]={0,0};
   GLint dxdy[]={ep[0]-sp[0],ep[1]-sp[1]};
   GLint pk = 2*dxdy[1]-dxdy[0];
   GLint *xkyk = sp;
   int i=1;
   plotter[0]=sp;

   while(memcmp(xkyk,ep,sizeof(ep))!=0){
       if(pk>=0){
           pk+=2*(dxdy[1]-dxdy[0]);
           xkyk[0]++;
           xkyk[1]++;
       }
       else{
           pk+=2*dxdy[1];
           xkyk[0]++;
       }
       if(i==sizeof(plotter))
        plotter=plotterresizer(plotter);
       plotter[i]=xkyk;
       i++;
   }
   return plotter;
 }

void lineSegment(void)
 {
    int i;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    GLint **plt = logic();
    // logic();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
      for(i=0;i<sizeof(plt);i++){
        glVertex2iv(plt[i]);
      }
      // glVertex2i (180,15);
      // glVertex2i (10, 145);
      // glVertex2i (21,34);
      // glVertex2i (111,9);
    glEnd();
    glFlush ();
 }

void main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition (25,50);
    glutInitWindowSize (200,150);
    glutCreateWindow ("Bresemham's Line Drawing Algorithm");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc (lineSegment);
    glutMainLoop();
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp2tT.png)

Comment: `sizeof(plt)` doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: So how can I know the size of plt? @Rabbid76

Comment: You cannot query it. You have to return it from the function. (e.g. return a struct with the pointer and the size)

Comment: I didn't understand exactly because I am a beginner in C. Could you modify my code to make it work? @Rabbid76

Comment: Why is the type of the vertex array `GLint**` and not `GLint*`?

Comment: Because it's a 2D array of Points where point itself is array.@Rabbid76

Comment: So where do you allocate the inner arrays?

Comment: See inside logic function. There are no line numbers here above.@Rabbid76 I by the way commented the for loop and uncommented the glVertex2i statements below and still its aborted.

Comment: Yes I can see it. However you just allocate the outer array, but you don't allocate the inner  arrays. Therefore you create an array of [Dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: GLint sp[]={9,18};     GLint *xkyk = sp;     plotter[i]=xkyk; @Rabbid76

Comment: Yes I can see that. Please learn the basics. This are [Dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: Ok sorry. Do you know where exactly I am going wrong? If you do, could you modify my code and paste it as an answer? Thank you.@Rabbid76

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer, but a guide to debug your program and will help to apply
the suggestions you just received by the others.
As the program is a X graphic one, you need to run NOT from the `Cygwin Terminal` but from `XTerm`. So install `xinit`, run `startxwin` and launch `Xterm`

Compile the program with debugging info, no optimization, and run GDB with it:

```
$ gcc -Wall -ggdb -O0 prova.c -o prova -lGL -lGLU -lglut

$ gdb ./prova.exe
```

inside GDB you will have

```
....
Reading symbols from ./prova.exe...
```

run the program

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/GL/prova.exe 
[New Thread 57376.0xef14]
....    
Thread 1 "prova" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff97139bebc in ig9icd64!DrvSetLayerPaletteEntries ()
   from /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/DriverStore/FileRepository/ki124757.inf_amd64_b607c305e0c4e0a1/ig9icd64.dll
```

shows the various frames in the stack

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ff97139bebc in ig9icd64!DrvSetLayerPaletteEntries ()
   from /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/DriverStore/FileRepository/ki124757.inf_amd64_b607c305e0c4e0a1/ig9icd64.dll
#1  0x000000010040127b in lineSegment () at prova.c:55
#2  0x00000003d2ffb35b in fghRedrawWindow () from /usr/bin/cygglut-3.dll
#3  0x00000003d2ffb6dc in fgProcessWork () from /usr/bin/cygglut-3.dll
#4  0x00000003d2ffd075 in fgEnumWindows () from /usr/bin/cygglut-3.dll
#5  0x00000003d2ffb7dd in glutMainLoopEvent () from /usr/bin/cygglut-3.dll
#6  0x00000003d2ffb876 in glutMainLoop () from /usr/bin/cygglut-3.dll
#7  0x0000000100401306 in main (argc=1, argv=0xffffcc70) at prova.c:75
```

going to the first one in your code

```
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x000000010040127b in lineSegment () at prova.c:55
55              glVertex2iv(plt[i]);
```

and we exam your variables

```
(gdb) p i
$1 = 6
(gdb) p plt[0]
$8 = (GLint *) 0xffffc9d0
(gdb) p plt[2]
$9 = (GLint *) 0xffffc9d0
(gdb) p plt[5]
$10 = (GLint *) 0xffffc9d0
(gdb) p plt[6]
$11 = (GLint *) 0x1000000010
```

So now you know where it segfaults.
it seems plt[6] is point to totally wrong memory area. Check the dimension of the object it seems is not 6.

Comment: I am using Xterm and XWin Server has 3 options, Cygwin Terminal, UXterm and Xterm.Text in Xterm looks like it was meant for low resolution displays so I am using Cygwin Terminal. Other programs work on both. Also why is plt(6) causing crash? I used square braces plt[i] and glVertex2iv() accepts an integer pointer which is given by plt[i].

Comment: `Cygwin Terminal` is usually run standalone, as you have not mentioned the X server, I misunderstood. I corrected the answer with the output of the debugger to show plt[6]